# Convert CString to const char*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

How do I convert from `CString` to `const char*` in my Unicode MFC application?

Comment: The fact that you are building a unicode program is KEY to this problem - PLEASE add this info to the question. (or someone with rep do it?)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To convert a `TCHAR` CString to ASCII, use the `CT2A` macro - this will also allow you to convert the string to UTF8 (or any other Windows code page):

```
// Convert using the local code page
CString str(_T("Hello, world!"));
CT2A ascii(str);
TRACE(_T("ASCII: %S\n"), ascii.m_psz);

// Convert to UTF8
CString str(_T("Some Unicode goodness"));
CT2A ascii(str, CP_UTF8);
TRACE(_T("UTF8: %S\n"), ascii.m_psz);

// Convert to Thai code page
CString str(_T("Some Thai text"));
CT2A ascii(str, 874);
TRACE(_T("Thai: %S\n"), ascii.m_psz);
```

There is also a macro to convert from ASCII -> Unicode (`CA2T`) and you can use these in ATL/WTL apps as long as you have VS2003 or greater.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(VS.80).aspx) for more info.

Comment: i already got the answer to the question a little bit earlier and you're right, I used the CT2A macro.

Thanks.

Comment: You could also do TRACE(_T("ASCII: %S\n"), CT2A(str).m_psz);

Comment: `CA2T` does **not** convert to Unicode. It converts to a `TCHAR` which may or may not represent Unicode characters. `CA2[C]W` is the macro that converts to Unicode.

Comment: The `CT2A ascii(str, CP_UTF8);` line solved the problem I reported on comments of http://stackoverflow.com/a/5551013/383779. Thanks.

Comment: Btw, none of the objects named `ascii` are in fact ASCII encoded strings. They are *narrow character strings*, using ANSI, UTF-8, and ANSI encoding (in that order).

Answer (score 27):

If your CString is Unicode, you'll need to do a conversion to multi-byte characters. Fortunately there is a version of CString which will do this automatically.

```
CString unicodestr = _T("Testing");
CStringA charstr(unicodestr);
DoMyStuff((const char *) charstr);
```

Comment: when i use this, i get this error : "Error 2 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CString' to 'ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>'"
"

Comment: @Attilah: Thanks for catching that, I had the syntax wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 19):

*Note: This answer predates the Unicode requirement; see the comments.*

Just cast it:

```
CString s;
const TCHAR* x = (LPCTSTR) s;
```

It works because CString has a cast operator to do exactly this.

Using TCHAR makes your code Unicode-independent; if you're not concerned about Unicode you can simply use `char` instead of `TCHAR`.

Comment: when i try your method, i get this error :
"Error 1 error C2664: 'CppSQLite3DB::execDML' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const TCHAR *' to 'const char *'".
my projetc settings use Unicode but the function CppSQLite3DB::execDML requires a const char* parameter.

Comment: As Mark says, you need to convert from a Unicode CString to an ANSI CStringA: CStringA charstr(unicodestr); You can then cast the CStringA to a const char*

Answer (score 5):

There is an explicit cast on CString to LPCTSTR, so you can do (provided unicode is not specified):

```
CString str;
// ....
const char* cstr = (LPCTSTR)str;
```

Comment: I got this error message :  error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'CString' to 'LPCSTR'

Comment: This answer is correct for ANSI CString. In case of Unicode CString, see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.  I had a `char*` buffer with the .so name in it.
I could not convert the `char*` variable to `LPCTSTR`.  Here's how I got around it...

```
char *fNam;
...
LPCSTR nam = fNam;
dll = LoadLibraryA(nam);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommendo to you use TtoC from ConvUnicode.h

```
const CString word= "hello";
const char* myFile = TtoC(path.GetString());
```

It is a macro to do conversions per Unicode

Answer (score 0):

Generic Conversion Macros (TN059 Other Considerations section is important):

```
A2CW     (LPCSTR)  -> (LPCWSTR)  
A2W      (LPCSTR)  -> (LPWSTR)  
W2CA     (LPCWSTR) -> (LPCSTR)  
W2A      (LPCWSTR) -> (LPSTR)
```

- [TN059: Using MFC MBCS/Unicode Conversion Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/805c56f8.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I used this conversion:

```
CString cs = "TEST";
char* c = cs.GetBuffer(m_ncs me.GetLength())
```

I hope this is useful.

Comment: In it's current form this code shouldn't work - what's "me"? what's "m_ncs"?

Answer (score 0):

I got it from Microsoft site and fullfill my problem, so sharing here
CString s(_T("ala bala portocala"));
char* c = (char*)(LPCTSTR)s;

Comment: Note that the OP is using **Unicode** - so the `CString` will be composed of `wchar_t` elements and a simple cast like you have shown will almost never work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34371682)