# Problem: How to convert CString into const char * in C++ MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

How do I convert CString into const char *? I have tried everything found on the internet but I still cant convert them.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert CString to const char*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CString casts to const char * directly

```
CString temp;
temp = "Wow";
const char * foo = (LPCSTR) temp;
printf("%s", foo);
```

will print 'foo'

Newer version of MFC also support the GetString() method:

```
CString temp;
temp = "Wow";
const char * foo = temp.GetString();
printf("%s", foo);
```

Comment: error C2440: 'type cast': cannot convert from 'ATL::CString' to 'LPCSTR'

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Use the `CT2CA` macro (see [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx)). This will work regardless of your project's 'Character Set' setting.

Long answer:

- If you have the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol defined (i.e., if `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`), use the `CT2CA` or `CW2CA` macro.
- If you don't (i.e., if `TCHAR` is `char`), CString already has an operator to convert to `char const*` implicitly (see [`CSimpleStringT::operator PCXSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk1z2hd9.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

If your application is not Unicode, you can simple typecast to `const char *`. Use the `GetBuffer()` method if you need a `char *` that you can modify.

If your application is Unicode and you really want a `char *`, then you'll need to convert it. (You can use functions like `MultiByteToWideChar()`.)

Answer (score -1):

I know it's late, but I couldn't use the marked-as-answer solution. I search all over the internet and nothing worked for me. I muscled through it to get a solution:

```
char * convertToCharArr(CString str) {
    int x = 0;
    string s = "";
    while (x < str.GetLength()) {
        char c = str.GetAt(x++);
        s += c;
    }
    char * output = (char *)calloc(str.GetLength() + 1, sizeof(char));
    memcpy(output, s.c_str(), str.GetLength() + 1);
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First : define  char *inputString; in your_file.h

Second : define in yourFile.cpp :
CString MyString;

```
MyString = "Place here whatever you want";

inputString = new char[MyString.GetLength()];
inputString = MyString.GetBuffer(MyString.GetLength());
```

The last two sentences convert a CString variable to a char*; but be carefull, with CString you can hold millons of charcteres but with char* no. You have to define the size of your char* varible.

Comment: The last 2 code lines ("sentences" as were named above) are bad programming. The first allocate a char array and copy its address in inputString . And the second code line will overwrite with the buffer allocated for MyString (pointer assignment is executed not array copying). Memory allocated by alloc is lost. If MyString is modified and so its buffer is freed and reallocated then inputString contains an invalid pointer. I will not comment on how much new char[] and CString allocate. So this is a very bad answer.