# How to convert CString to ofstream?

Tags: c++

I have a few CString variables that I wish to output to an ofstream, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so. Here's some example code.

I have unicode enabled in VS 2005

CODE:

```
  ofstream ofile;
  CString str = "some text";

  ofile.open(filepath);
   ofile << str; // doesn't work, gives me some hex value such as 00C8F1D8 instead
    ofile << str.GetBuffer(str.GetLength()) << endl; // same as above
     ofile << (LPCTSTR)str << endl; // same as above

   // try copying CString to char array
  char strary[64];
  wcscpy_s(strary, str.GetBuffer()); // strary contents are correctly copied
  ofile << strary << endl ; // same hex value problem again!
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: if you use UNICODE then strary should be wchar_t not char.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want plain ACP encoded ANSI text:

```
    ofile << CT2A(str);
```

ofstream formatted output functions expect narrow/ansi strings.

CStrings represent TCHAR strings.

The CT2A macro Converts TCHAR 2 Ansi.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/libr...8VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Tried this working with wofstream and I got "????????? (????????)" for "български"

Comment: BTW link is dead.

Answer (score 9):

If using UNICODE, why don't you use wofstream, which is a basic_stream parametrized with wchar_t. This works as expected:

```
  CString str = _T("some text");
  std::wofstream file;
  file.open(_T("demo.txt"));
  file << (LPCTSTR)str;
```

Comment: I had my code like this; it works well with English/Latin languages, but not with Bulgarian/CJK ! :(

Comment: My problem has been solved as reported in my comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/859841/383779