# How to convert CString to const char *

Tags: constants, cstring

I have problems converting CString to const char *. I tried the methods from other forums and msdn way and it doesn't work:

```
CString value1("text1");
const char * value2= LPCTSTR(value1);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert CString to const char\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char)

Answer (score -1):

Get pointer of the internal character buffer of CString

```
const char * value2 = (const char *) value1.GetBuffer( value1.GetLength() );
```

Release the buffer when done.

```
value1.ReleaseBuffer()
```

The ReleaseBuffer() gives ownership of the buffer back to CString.

Comment: -1 : answer cintains c style cast and no explanation.whatsoever

Comment: error C2039: 'Release' : is not a member of 'ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>'

Comment: @MartinBa MSDN explains the functions but I added a bit :)