# Converting CString to type char?

Tags: c++

I know this may be a silly question to an expert but I'm just wondering is it possible to pass a variable of type CString into a function declared below when called?

```
void LoadFile(char * szFileName);
```

The folowing error occurs: 'LoadFile' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'class CString' to 'char *'...

Can I convert the string somehow?

Thankyou for your comments...

Comment: Almost certainly, but what is a `CString`? (It's not standard C++...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char

Comment: @Cameron: `CString` is a Microsoft-specific class. A Google search turned up this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688%28v=vs.60%29.aspx (Yes, that should have been explained in the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler is telling you exactly what is wrong. You're passing a custom object `CString` and the function you're calling is expecting a c-styled string (char * with a null terminator).

What you need is to access the c-style string that your `CString` class is wrapping. You can find more information about this at the MSDN documentation page [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300569(v=vs.60).aspx).

Simply cast your argument as an `LPCSTR`.

```
CString file("somefile.txt");
LoadFile((LPCSTR)file);
```

Answer (score 2):

Freddy's answer is almost correct.  The problem is really in the signature of LoadFile().  It probably should not be taking a char* argument.  It should probably be taking a const char* argument.  Are you planning on modifying the passed in string into LoadFile()?  If not, make it const if the source is under your control--and if you won't break too many things.

In reality, you would have to do this:

```
CString filename("somefile.txt");
LoadFile((LPSTR)(LPCSTR) filename); // need the extra cast to (LPSTR)
```

or

```
LoadFile((LPSTR) filename.GetString());
```

This is all assuming you aren't building for Unicode.  If you are building for Unicode, it's going to be different.

If you were building for Unicode, I would have changed the function signature to:

```
void LoadFile(LPCTSTR szFileName); // LPCTSTR == const TCHAR* (TCHAR is char for MBCS and wchar_t for Unicode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GetBuffer` member function, which returns LPSTR...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: `GetBuffer()` returns an `LPTSTR` (note the **T**).

Comment: yes, but the definition of `LPTSTR` depends on whether `UNICODE` is defined or not

Comment: Exactly. And when `UNICODE` is defined, it's a `ẁchar_t *`, which does not convert to `char *`. As Joe notes in the answer above, the problem is actually more in the signature of `LoadFile()`.