# Converting form CString to const char*

Tags: c++, constants, c-strings

I've wrote a method that convert form `CString` to `const char *`:

```
const char* CAESDlg::ConvertToChar(CString str) {
    CStringA charstr(str);
    const char *cstr = (const char *)charstr;
    return cstr;
}
```

but when trying to put it in a `const char *` it doesn't return the correct value!

```
const char *test = ConvertToChar(filePath);
```

Comment: We cannot know what a `CString` is.

Comment: How are `CString` and `CStringA` defined?

Comment: while debugging cstr contains a valid value , but in this line      const char *test = ConvertToChar(filePath); it equal a wrong value

Comment: Your function is returning a dangling pointer. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I've a CString that i want to convert to const char * to pass it to a method that take const char *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `charstr` gets destroyed at the end of the function before the caller assigns it to variable.

You don't need a function, the caller can use `CStringA` directly and note that `test` is valid before `sFilePathA` goes out of scope.

```
CStringA sFilePathA(filePath);
const char *test = sFilePathA;
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing `CString` and `CStringA` I can only guess, but it seems as if you are returning a pointer to a local variable, which is UB, as soon as you access value the pointer points to.

If you want to use a `CString` object as a `const char*` parameter you probably want to use [LPCTSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/awkwbzyc.aspx) instead of your self-written `ConvertToChar` function.

Comment: @AhmedAli: There are multiple possibilities, depending on how you want to use the function, but personally I'd suggest not to use `const char*` at all, but `std::string`. Btw: you should probably have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char)

Comment: @AhmedAli: See my edit in response to the information in your comments.

Comment: i got this error while trying to use LPCTSTR 

a value of type LPCTSTR can't be used to initialize an entity of type const char *