# VC 6.0 MFC How to read unicode data from sql server into CListBox

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, bstr

I have created a VC6.0 MFC app. I also set the project in unicode mode.
[image][image]

But I when I load the unicode data (e.g. Russian) from sql db, I also get question mark string "????..."

```
_variant_t TheValue;

CString str;
try
{
    m_list.ResetContent();
    //m_pConnection.CreateInstance(_uuidof(Connection));
    m_pRecordset.CreateInstance(_uuidof(Recordset));

    m_pRecordset->Open("SELECT * FROM MyUser",(IDispatch*)m_pConnection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic,adCmdText);

    while(!m_pRecordset->adoEOF)
    {
        TheValue = m_pRecordset->GetCollect("name");
        if(TheValue.vt!=VT_NULL)
        {
            str=(LPCSTR)_bstr_t(TheValue);
            m_list.AddString(str);

        }

        m_pRecordset->MoveNext();       
    }
    m_pRecordset->Close();
}
catch(_com_error e)
{
    CString errormessage;
    errormessage.Format(L"Connect failedr\n error:%s", e.ErrorMessage());
    AfxMessageBox(errormessage);
}
```

Comment: You cast a BSTR to a char*. This isn't allowed. What type is m_List? It doesn't seam to be a unicode aware data class.

Comment: This cast is wrong `str=(LPCSTR)_bstr_t(TheValue);`

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d123cbc8-51c8-439a-a90d-bcbda728b539/conversion-of-bstr-to-cstring?forum=vcmfcatl) may help.

Comment: xMRi, the m_List is type of CListBox

Comment: `str=(LPCSTR)_bstr_t(TheValue);` should be `str=(LPCSTRT)_bstr_t(TheValue);` — notice the **T**

Comment: See also See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char/859841#859841