# Convert WCHAR to LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, mfc

With `CSocket`, I want to make a connect with an IP address.

```
CSocket client;
client.Create();
client.Connect(IP, 80);
```

But `IP` is defined `WCHAR ip[16];`

`client.Connect(IP, 80)` requires `IP` is `LPCTSTR` type

How can I convert from `WCHAR` to `LPCTSTR` ?

Comment: Please post the error you received when you attempted to use `WCHAR`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert CString to const char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char)

Answer (score 0):

If you build for the Unicode character set (as any Windows program more recent than about 2000 should), `LPCTSTR`  will be a typedef for `LPCWSTR` aka `wchar_t const *`, and a `wchar_t[]` array would decay to that.

If you build for the Multibyte character set, you'll have to convert your data. I suggest using `CW2T()` for that (it is actually a class, but is almost always used as a temporary object), eg:

```
client.Connect(CW2T(ip), 80);
```