# Redirection of a std::list<CString> content to a text file

Tags: c++, winapi, std, lpcstr

I am using that code to enumerate files with specific extensions in a drive and write them out to a text file.
It outputs something like this in the text file. How can I write file address with their names instead of these **garbage values**.
00000281BBACF338
00000281BBACEA78
00000281BBACF108
00000281BBAD1E48

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlpath.h>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#ifdef _UNICODE
#define cout wcout
#endif

void FindFiles(
    const CString& strRootPath,
    const CString& strExt,
    std::list<CString>& listFiles,
    bool bRecursive = true)
{
    CString strFileToFind = strRootPath;
    ATLPath::Append(CStrBuf(strFileToFind, MAX_PATH), _T("*.*"));

    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData = { 0 };
    HANDLE hFileFind = ::FindFirstFile(strFileToFind, &findData);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFileFind)
    {
        do
        {
            CString strFileName = findData.cFileName;
            if ((strFileName == _T(".")) || (strFileName == _T("..")))
                continue;

            CString strFilePath = strRootPath;
            ATLPath::Append(CStrBuf(strFilePath, MAX_PATH), strFileName);
            if (bRecursive && (ATLPath::IsDirectory(strFilePath)))
            {
                FindFiles(strFilePath, strExt, listFiles);
            }
            else
            {
                CString strFoundExt = ATLPath::FindExtension(strFilePath);
                if (!strExt.CompareNoCase(strFoundExt))
                    listFiles.push_back(strFilePath);
            }

        } while (::FindNextFile(hFileFind, &findData));

        ::FindClose(hFileFind);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open("test.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app | std::ios::binary);

    std::list<CString> listFiles;
    FindFiles(_T("D:\\"), _T(".txt"), listFiles);
    for (const auto& strFile : listFiles)
        file << (LPCTSTR)strFile.GetString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cast `strfile` to `LPCTSTR`, and write the file stream of `ofstream`, the character sets of the two do not match.

You can use `wofstream` to solve this problem:

```
std::wofstream file;
```

Or use `CT2A` function to convert it:

```
for (const auto& strFile : listFiles)
    file << CT2A(strFile) << std::endl;
```

More reference : [Convert CString to const char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859304/convert-cstring-to-const-char/859841#859841)